# Spring mvc Service Example vs Hibernate Repository Query

Tags: spring, hibernate, repository

I'm sorry to ask many questions these days but i'm on my own. 
I would like to know exactly when I have to create a new query in repository and when I have to filter data in service. 
For example to get a person by name you can do it in more than 2 differents ways.

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE LOWER(p.name) = LOWER(:name)")
    Person findOneByName(@Param("name") String name);

}
```

and

```
@Service
public class PersonService implements IService<Person,Integer>{
...
  public Person findOneByName(String name){
        Person personFilter = new Person();
        personFilter.setName(name);
        ExampleMatcher matcher = ExampleMatcher.matching().withIgnoreCase().withIgnoreNullValues();

        Example<Person > example = Example.of(personFilter,matcher);

        return personRepository.findOne(example);
    }
...
}
```

I prefere use the first one because it's easier to implement when do we use Example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use the first one in the simply cases when you can do work by one JPQL (HQL) request.

If you need to build request depending on conditions use the second approach.
Something like:

```
if (filter.hasName()) {
  addNameToExample();
}

if (filter.hasAge()) {
  addAgeToExample();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your post it was really helpful.
I've just found out an other case where Example is usefull when you want to do a generic method in a generic service since you can't refer inside the generic repository to an Entity so it's impossible to use jpql.